# Why call function in window scope is different from object scope

Tags: javascript

Why calling Person in window scope is returning "[Object Object]" while call that in object scope is returning Object.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Well, just don't do `Person.call(window, …)`. That'll attempt to set `window.name`. And no, this has nothing to do with scopes - if you refer to the `this` keyword, that's the *context* or *receiver* of the call.

Answer (score 1):

global `window` object already have a property of `name`, and it's inside the scope of native code.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_name.asp

Answer (score 0):

[`window.name`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name) is a getter/setter to set the name of the window. As such, it has to be of type `string`.

Try this:

```
window.name = ["something", "else"];
```

You will see that now `window.name` is set to `"something,else"`; which is the result of `Array.toString()`.

This is exactly what is happening here. When you call an `object`'s `toString`, you get `[object Object]`.

Your program works fine if you do not use the predefined `window.name` getter/setter.

```js
function Person(first, last) {
    this.something = {
        first,
        last
    };
}

f = {};

Person.call(f, "fsd", "fsd");
console.log(f.something);

g = window;
Person.call(g, "fsd", "fsd");
console.log(g.something);
```

More on getter/setters in javascript:

Setters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Getters: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get